# Matter and Antimatter Interaction in the early Universe

Tags: big-bang-theory, early-universe, antimatter

Well it is said that during the Big Bang, things were created in pairs: one matter and one anti-matter. I think its a part of the Big-Bang Theory.

It is also said that matter + anti-matter - Energy

Then shouldn't it be so that there would have been no matter or antimatter in existence now since all of them should have reacted to form pure Energy. I mean how were we created then?

And also where are all the antimatter gone now? Are they still reacting with us?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matter and antimatter aren't perfectly symmetric, when following the "forward" direction of time. This is commonly called [charge-parity violation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP_violation).
It's assumed, that this asymmetry caused an excess of matter in the early stages of the Universe after the Big Bang, annihilating almost all antimatter, and leaving behind matter.

Comment: So where are they now?  If you're still here this should be still eating away matter.

Comment: Thus far, no indication for anti-stars have been found, although detectors have looked for atomic anti-nuclei in cosmic rays. But it has been considered, that antimatter may form temporarily on some neutron stars. After contact with matter, antimatter is annihilated in a gamma flash, "eating" matter. Antimatter forms from high-energy gamma rays hitting matter. Due to the usual presence of matter this antimatter will be short-lived. But one cannot rule out, that it can escape sometimes, and live until an encounter with matter.

Answer (score 0):

This paper gives a possible explanation as to the missing antimatter, it suggests matter collides with antimatter in such a way the resultant ejected particles are real on-mass shell particles

[Antimatter and the Big Bang](http://www.vixra.org/pdf/1811.0284v1.pdf), J.C.O'Brien